# Terminal window get maximized

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Don't know what went wrong my terminal window maximized to the screen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unmaximize use:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>F10</kbd>

If none working:

**Press**  <kbd>F11</kbd> without <kbd>Alt</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for Response but it didn't worked. !

Comment: I tried every button from Alt + F1- F12

Comment: __Nope just F11__ without ALT

Comment: ((((((((F11 )))))))) it worked :D

Comment: It's also possible to use devilspie to force a window to always be maximized by default, or to *never* be maximized by default. Sometimes useful, because evince will like to open PDFs hanging off your screen.